# How many messianic prophecies in the Tanach?

Tags: tanach, messiah, nevua-prophecy

Xtians make the bold claim that their j-sus fulfilled over 300 prophecies from the Hebrew Scriptures. Most of them are either verses taken out of context, mistranslations of Hebrew, some remote resemblance to j-sus, or just complete fabrications.

My question is how many actual messianic prophecies are there in the Tanach? If a verse promises more than one thing and it pertains to Mashiach, it’s more than one prophecy as pertains to this question.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's debatable. Some passages are considered by sages as Messianic while others disagree (ex. Gen 49:10). The thing to remember is the Tanakh focuses on the Messianic age that is ushered in not the person.

Comment: Doesn’t *quite* answer the question. The second sentence is completely irrelevant, since he asks how many messianic prophecies there are, without regard to what specifically they’re about. The first sentence, while true, doesn’t really answer the question.

Comment: I'm really not seeing a direct answer to the question. Surely there are specific prophecies pertaining to Moshiach himself. Granted there are prophecies of events that will take place as a result of his arrival but my question is specific to the NUMBER OF PROPHECIES that are in the Tanach relating to HIM vs. the 300 or more xtian prophecies they say are already fulfilled.

Comment: You asked for how many and I say it's debatable because sometimes Christians claim something is messianic in nature and Jews will disagree. So it depends on what viewpoint you are looking at it from. Per Zechariah they should be coming to the Jews to learn about their God so they should be the ruling authority on it thus making all claims from Christians irrelevant